# print output of dictionary different from dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

Print gives me a different dictionary with regards to sorting. My keys have changed position. Why?

```
LETTER_VALUES = {
    'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10
}

print LETTER_VALUES

'''
output of LETTER_VALUES
'''

{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 3, 'e': 1, 'd': 2, 'g': 2, 'f': 4, 'i': 1, 'h': 4, 'k': 5, 'j': 8, 'm': 3, 'l': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'q': 10, 'p': 3, 's': 1, 'r': 1, 'u': 1, 't': 1, 'w': 4, 'v': 4, 'y': 4, 'x': 8, 'z': 10}
```

Sorted differently (Why is this?)

Answer (score 0):

Elements in Python dictionaries are **unsorted**. Check out [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). From the python docs:

```
>>> # regular unsorted dictionary
>>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

>>> # dictionary sorted by key
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])

>>> # dictionary sorted by value
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)])

>>> # dictionary sorted by length of the key string
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[0])))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('apple', 4), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Default, `dict` is not sorted. That is why there is no ordering to maintain. If you want sorted dictionary you have to use - `OrderedDict`